# How does C# compiler determine reference equality in generic methods when operator overloads for a specified type exists?

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading, equality

Currently going through Jon Skeet's "C# In Depth, 3rd edition" and I have a small question concerning reference equality. For those interested, the following code is a small variation of Jon's code from Chptr 3. p.80:

Public Function stored in a class; note that 'T' is constrained to  reference types:

```
    public static bool AreReferencesEqual<T>(T i1, T i2) where T : class
    {
        return i1 == i2;
    }
```

Driver method:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name = "Joe";
        string one = "one" + name;
        string two = "one" + name;
        // test one (uses string operator== overload, and returns true)
        Console.WriteLine(one == two);

        // test two (according to Jon, when the compiler compiles the generic method,
        // it has no idea what overloads will be provided, and therefore treats
        // the == comparison with respect to the more general 'object' type.
        // Therefore this method should return false because, of course, the value
        // of the references 'one' and 'two' are not the same.
        Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquality.AreReferencesEqual(one, two));
    }
```

In consistency with Jon's explanation, the output of the driver file when I run it is "True", "False".  Now, I thought I understood this completely, but I was surprised when I changed the driver file to this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string one = "one";
        string two = "one";
        Console.WriteLine(one == two);
        Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquality.AreReferencesEqual(one, two));
    }
```

and saw "True", "True" on the output.  What is the reasoning behind this?  Is the generic method now using the string operator== overload, or are the references indeed equal as a result of some subtle compiler technique I am unaware of?  Or have I completely missed the boat and misinterpreted Jon's explanation?

Thanks for taking the time to read and respond.

Comment: Please address him as Lord Skeet, he will address you directly

Comment: @CarbineCoder Ha, thanks.  I imagine I will take this advice as I continue advancing into his book.  Cheers.

Comment: Equality is confusing in C#. You might be interested in this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty/ and this http://blog.coverity.com/2014/01/13/inconsistent-equality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are reference-equivalent because the compiler is using the same underlying string because the constants match.  Strings (behind the scenes) are immutable in C# - when you add strings together, a new string instance is generated - that never happens in your second code set, so they are, in fact, both referencing the same chunk of bytes in RAM.

Comment: You can verify this for yourself too. Change your assignment of string two to be something like    string two = "on" + "e";

Comment: Hmm...  So the compiler can tell if the underlying character array is equal via an optimization technique?  Why doesn't the first code set benefit from this?  The underlying array for 'one' is equal to 'two' despite the concatenation (as we can see from output of string operator== in test one, code set 1).  If the compiler is performing these techniques based on the constant value of the string, wouldn't it be able to see that I've used the same call (even if it is concatenation), and therefore just use the same reference like it does in set one? If not, why not?

Comment: Either way, your question definitely answers the "What" that is going on, so I accepted it!  If you could provide a little more information as to my above question regarding "How", though, I'd very much appreciate it!

Comment: '+' is a run-time operation for reference-based objects (it can be overloaded, etc.) and so the compiler does not do any optimization there - even though technically String is a baked-in class, it doesn't get any special treatment with respect to the compiler's understanding of what '+' means (in this case that it is straight concatenation of two constants which means yes, a shared constant could have been used).

Comment: @otto-null That clarifies things a lot.  Thanks again.

Comment: @JoshuaMacvey The compiler is actually willing to do the optimization if you promise him that `name` will always refer to the same string, i.e. if you change `string name = "Joe"` to `const string name = "Joe"` the output of the first example will also be "True", "True".